# ECMAScript String.prototype.slice spec: "sourceLength+start"

Tags: javascript

It says "sourceLength+start" where I understand "sourceLength-start". What is the definition?

Today I looked in the ECMA-Script specs for 
[string.prototype.slice()](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.13) and I'm a little bit confused. For a negative argument it says: "If start is negative, it is treated as sourceLength+start where sourceLength is the length of the String." 
But then I examine a simple example like this:

```
var source = "Hello world!";
console.log(source.length); // 12
var substring = source.slice(-6);
console.log(substring); // world!
```

For me it looks like it does something like this: sourceLength == 12, substract 6 from 12, so start on position 6.

If I imagine it would be a conversation between the script and the interpreter it would look something like this: Interpreter: "hey, that is the length of the string?", Script: "12", Interpreter: "Okay good, I have here an negative start-argument, so lets substract this number (-6) from the length and start there".

Can somebody tell me the idea about the specs explanation? I don't get it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that if `start` is negative, the result of `length + start` is a number **lower** than the length. In your example, `12 + -6` is `6` — which is where `world!` starts. The spec is literal. It *could* have said "If *start* is negative, subtract *abs(start)* from *sourceLength*" (where `abs` is taking the absolute value), but just adding the negative number is the simple way.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of -6 as "6 with a minus sign in front of it", rather than "a number which is 6 below zero".

If you add -6 to 12, you get 6; if you *subtract* -6 from 12, you'd get 18.

Comment: Your first sentence really nails it.

Answer (score 0):

Cause

```
array.length + (-5)
```

Returns the right offset.